# Session is being abandoned in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have an asp.net c# web application running on a server, My application keeps sending me to the login page even after 1 minute, My server provider say nothing is wrong on the server configurations, I have defined my web.config file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=123.123.123.123;User ID=myUserID;Password=myPassword;"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" defaultLanguage="c#">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
  </httpHandlers>
<machineKey
validationKey="374A70A6EF0A2F8C1F821D125FCF6503DEA7E9CE467B433086B058D86FAB67338
C3A37E580F29FF27E86D079CC9153E396ABF495821E84C7B7B1F42F4467F1CA"
 decryptionKey="C74E21EE5B3C592C62C1BC5E682ED3CC4BD389CCC3AEA317AE1772E0D6750141"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
 <handlers>
  <add name="CaptchaImage" verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.CaptchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha"/>
 </handlers>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
   <error statusCode="404" path="~/pr/http404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
 </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

And in my .aspx files I use the below code to check the session

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null || userRole() != "Admin")
            Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx", false);
        else
        {
            // some code here..
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        litAlert.Text = "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><div><span><strong>An error has occured. Please try again</strong></span ></div></div>";
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: have you checked your Session Timeout settings in IIS? do you have an IIS admin..?

Comment: I don'y have IIS in my control panel, I have ASP.NET Configuration for Website and in section Session Settings I have set the Session timeout (minutes) to 30 minutes

Comment: Session["user"] have value in it ? you checked ?

Comment: YES. In order to see the pages i have to login via login.aspx, but in a very short time the session is being abandoned and I am redirected to the login.aspx page again.